# HG Command not working from php

Tags: php, shell, mercurial

I have a basic deployment procedure in place and I want to automate it.I am using php to automate from Php i am calling shell script. If i use php & shell script HG command not working.

Below is my Sample code.

index.php

```
<?php
startBuild();

function startBuild() {
    echo shell_exec('sh makeBuild.sh 2>&1');
}
?>
```

makeBuild.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
hg pull <hg-path>
hg archive -r1673 --verbose /Users/system1/Sites/Apps/001225035079/1.3
```

Browser i am running

```
http://localhost/~system1/Sites/index.php
```

While executing the webpage am getting an error as 'makeStandalone.sh: line 7: hg: command not found makeStandalone.sh: line 8: hg: command not found'

If i run makeBuild.sh from Terminate.app it working perfectly.

Please help me to solve this problem, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the full path to the `hg` executable would help in this case. Change your script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/hg pull <hg-path>
/path/to/hg archive -r1673 --verbose /Users/system1/Sites/Apps/001225035079/1.3
```

Replace `/path/to/hg` with the correct path for your install.

Comment: Thanks Vikram, need little bit of clarity. My Hg clone path is '/Users/system1/Sites/Apps/' so i given /Users/system1/Sites/Apps/ hg pull <hg-path>. Is it correct ?

Comment: I am talking about the hg executable path, not the repository path. What is the output of `which hg` in the terminal?

Comment: Thanks Vikram it's working. `#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/hg pull <hg-path>
/usr/local/bin/hg archive -r1673 --verbose /Users/system1/Sites/Apps/001225035079/1.3`.